# htaccess - How to redirect old urls to new pretty ones?

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I'm using opencart seo urls and they work fine. The problem is that I can access the old url too which results in duplicate content.

**Example:**

My new SEO Url is:
http://site.com/blue-widgets

The problem is that I can access the old one too and I'm afraid to get penalized by the search enghines for having duplicate content:
http://site.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=113

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Check my edited answer - Google won't penalize OpenCart product pages.

Answer (score 2):

I consider the problem of duplicate contents as kind of insufficiency within OpenCart.

**But** if You started to use **only** SEO URLs and if You are sure there is no old link to a concrete product that could be found and followed/indexed by robots You are safe.

Google (and others) could punish You if You were using both old and new URLs within You eshop (like the SEO ones dynamically generated and the old ones hardwritten somewhere within information pages...).

There is also other possible duplicit content problem - consider a product that is linked with more categories (if the product is linked to a third-level category it should also be linked to its second-level parent and also first-level parent) - then You can access this product from each category it is linked to and the URL will always be different (let's assume http://my.shop.com/televisions/3d-led-samsung is the very same product as http://my.shop.com/televisions/3d/3d-led-samsung and also as http://my.shop.com/televisions/3d/led/3d-led-samsung) - but here Google should not punish Your eshop as the name of the product 3d-led-samsung is always the same and Google should recognize it.

So I wouldn't be affraid of this.

**EDIT:** As **Stann0rz** pointed out, OpenCart automatically uses `canonical` links thus there is no reason to be affraid of Google penalizing You for duplicit content. Problem solved!

Comment: Canonical link elements (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) overcome this.

Comment: @Stann0rz Yep, but this way You would have to set `rel="canonical"` to all links leading to product details that means Google will look on that like "Ooooh, what? They wanna fool me? Low page rank on them!". :-D

Comment: It only needs to be specified in the <head> tags of the relevant page (http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) - OpenCart does this automatically (http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41)

Comment: @Stann0rz Well, then there is no reason to be affraid of duplicit content :-) That's a good news to me! Thank You!